# Save the multiple images into PDF without chainging the format of Subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've a `df` like this as shown below. What I'm doing is I'm trying to loop through the `df` column(s) with paths & printing the image as sub plots one column with image paths at `axis0` and other column paths parallely on `axis1` as follows.

```
      identity       VGG-Face_cosine    img                 comment
0   ./clip_v4/3.png   1.110223e-16  .\clip_v3\0.png        .\clip_v3\0.png is matched with ./clip_v4/3.png
0   ./clip_v4/2.png   2.220446e-16  .\clip_v3\1.png        .\clip_v3\1.png is matched with ./clip_v4/2.png
1   ./clip_v4/4.png   2.220446e-16  .\clip_v3\1.png        .\clip_v3\1.png is matched with ./clip_v4/4.png
2   ./clip_v4/5.png   2.220446e-16  .\clip_v3\1.png        .\clip_v3\1.png is matched with ./clip_v4/5.png
0   ./clip_v4/2.png   2.220446e-16  .\clip_v3\2.png        .\clip_v3\2.png is matched with
```

I'm looping through these 2 columns `identity`  and  `img` columns & plotting as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import rcParams


df = df.iloc[1:]
#merged_img = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # figure size in inches optional
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 11 ,8

    # read images
    
    img_A = mpimg.imread(row['identity'])
    img_B = mpimg.imread(row['img'])

    # display images
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
 
    
    ax[0].imshow(img_A)
    ax[1].imshow(img_B)
```

sample output I got.

**###Console output**

[image: sample console output]

Upto now it's fine. My next idea is to save these images as it is with sublots on `PDF`. I don't want to change the structure the way it prints. Like I just want 2 images side by side in PDF too. I've went through many available solutions. But, I can't relate my part of code with the logic avaiable in `documentation`. Is there is any way to achieve my goal?. Any references would be helpful!!. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to save the figure?  Fig.savefig will save as pdf

Comment: Hi @JodyKlymak I've tried...As you can see we are printing only 2 images at once for one `iteration` . It's not appending images...Only last 2 images are getting saved

Comment: Put the savefig in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PdfPages` from `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf` to save figures one by one on separate pages of the same pdf-file:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

df = df.iloc[1:]
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 11 ,8
pdf_file_name = 'my_images.pdf' 

with PdfPages(pdf_file_name) as pdf:

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        img_A = mpimg.imread(row['identity'])
        img_B = mpimg.imread(row['img'])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
        ax[0].imshow(img_A)
        ax[1].imshow(img_B)

        # save the current figure at a new page in pdf_file_name
        pdf.savefig()
```

See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the figures in one, you need to set up your axis in advance with the right number of subplots:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import rcParams

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "identity": ["0.png", "2.png", "4.png"],
        "img": ["1.png", "3.png", "5.png"],
    }
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(df), 2, figsize=(11, 8*len(df)))

for [index, row], axrow in zip(df.iterrows(), ax):

    # read images
    img_A = mpimg.imread(row["identity"])
    img_B = mpimg.imread(row["img"])

    # display images

    axrow[0].imshow(img_A)
    axrow[1].imshow(img_B)

plt.savefig("all_images.png")
plt.close()
```

This is what the output looks like (input is a handful of stackoverflow user pics):

[image: row_0]
[image: row_1]
[image: row_2]

Comment: Hi @mmdanziger...your answer makes sense...But why I'm geeting 3 different pdf's? I'm expecting all the images in 1 PDF...We need to append to same PDF

Comment: oh! that wasn't clear. you want an arbitrarily tall pdf?

Comment: Yes...I want to save all the images in 1 PDF{with same format} ...Sorry for mis clarrification

Comment: then you need to declare the number of axes at onset, see edit

Comment: I've to save final image as `pdf` Is there is any argument to reduce size between images...As you can see there is lot of space b/w appended images

Comment: Re the space you should tweak the figsize based on the geometry of your particular images. Also add a plt.tight_layout

Comment: Re appending, don't append rows, populate the existing rows with images. You don't want to dynamically resize unless you really have to

Comment: Let me try @mmdanziger...I want to check once with larger list of images..I was worried that If there are many images...It may get blurry while viewing as we need to zoom to see images..This was a nice solution!!!